# Integrate Azure Key Vault With Azure Kubernetes Service using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aad-pod-identity

I'm setting up Keyvault integration with k8s in Azure.  I can mount a volume with secrets using the csi driver in Azure using Managed identities. I can verify the secret is mounted by exec-ing into the pod and cat-ing out the secrets. However, now I want to expose the secrets as environment variables, but I'm unclear how to do that.  Below is the following `SecretProviderClass` and `Pod` I have deployed.

spc-keyvault.yaml:

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: spc-keyvault
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: foobar-secret
    data:
    - key: foobar
      objectName: foobar
    type: Opaque
  parameters:
    keyvaultName: "$keyvault"
    usePodIdentity: "true"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "false"
    userAssignedIdentityID: ""
    cloudName: ""
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: foobar
          objectType: secret
          objectVersion: ""
    resourceGroup: "$resourceGroup"
    subscriptionId: "$subId"
    tenantId: "$tenantId"
```

pod.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: inject-secrets-from-akv
  labels:
    aadpodidbinding: azure-pod-identity-binding-selector
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      env:
      - name: SECRET
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: foobar-secret
            key: foobar
      volumeMounts:
      - name: secrets-store-inline
        mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: secrets-store-inline
      csi:
        driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
        readOnly: true
        volumeAttributes:
          secretProviderClass: spc-keyvault
```

Here's the error when I deploy my Pod manifest:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  Failed   58m (x227 over 108m)    kubelet  Error: secret "foobar-secret" not found
  Normal   Pulling  3m51s (x470 over 108m)  kubelet  Pulling image "nginx"
```

The error is pretty obvious, there is no secret named: `foobar-secret`. I thought the csi driver automatically created the required secrets.  So after some research and digging throught documentation and source code, I found a suggestion to add `nodePublishSecretRef` in the pod yaml. Then you need to set `nodePublishSecretRef` with the aad client id and client secret.[1, 2]  However since I'm using managed identity I'm unsure how to do this.

Has anyone got this working using Managed Identity and can provide any insight?  Or do i need to create a startup script (via configmap?) to populate the volume mount as env. variables.

1. https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/configurations/identity-access-modes/service-principal-mode/
2. https://medium.com/swlh/integrate-azure-key-vault-with-azure-kubernetes-service-1a8740429bea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more digging around, I found this bit to tickle in the helm chart to get the csi driver to create k8s secrets:

```
secrets-store-csi-driver.syncSecret.enabled = true
```

Now I have k8s secrets. Figured I would share for anyone else wanting this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to solve this issue by updating the entrypoint.sh to export the secrets to env variables. Something like this:

```sh
if [ ! -z ${SECRET_PATH+x} ]
then

  echo "Exporting secrets as env. variables."
  for f in $(ls ${SECRET_PATH})
  do

    echo "Exporting $f..."
    export $f=$(cat ${SECRET_PATH}/$f)

  done

fi
```